# (empty list or set) from redis-cli when run from bash

Tags: bash, shell, redis

I have 3 dummy keys stored in my local redis server.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "key2"
2) "key3"
3) "key1"
```

When I try to fetch the same results from bash it returns "(empty list or set)" . Why?

```
$ redis-cli keys *
(empty list or set)
```

Answer (score 17):

Just remembered that '*' has special meaning in bash. So

```
redis-cli keys \*
```

works.

Comment: I AM THAT POOR SOUL! hahaha

Comment: OK I'm that poor (and stupid) soul too, and I might add that `KEYS *;` is not at all equal to `KEYS *`. Beginners coming to Redis from SQL might be tempted to add semicolon at the end of the line as I was — don't do it